# Why can i not connect to NodeJS express server from any network?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, networking, ip

Lets say that i have a web server running on port 3001 and my ip is 23.512.531.56 (not an actual ip address btw) and i go onto another network, like my neighbours or something, if i type in chrome `23.512.531.56:3001`why can i not get a response from the server? here is my nodeJS code.

```
//"Imports" libraries reqired.

const express = require("express");
const fs = require("fs");

//Starts express

const svr = express();

//Main

svr.get("/", (req, res)=>{
    fs.createReadStream("./html/index.html").pipe(res);
});

svr.get("/image0.png", (req, res) => {
    fs.createReadStream("./html/image0.png").pipe(res);
});

//Sets port to host on

svr.listen(3001);
```

Comment: You must open port 3001  to the outside and bind to your local machine (Port forwarding). Have a look into your router! And if it is not a fixed IP use a DynDNS service.

Comment: Sure with pleasure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to be in the same network. For example, if you are using different wifi (from your neighbors) you can't access your local NodeJs server. You can get to your server if your devices are under the same default gateway.

If you want to access it from any network, you might want to deploy it to a global network.

One thing to add, *even for illustration don't use an IP address that is not right*

Comment: 23.512.531.56 Is an public IP not local and if so, the neighbor must also be in the same network.

Answer (score 1):

You must open port 3001 to the outside and bind to your local machine (Port forwarding). Have a look into your router! And if it is not a fixed IP use a DynDNS service.